# How do you await each iteration of a filter loop instead of the completion of an entire loop?

Tags: javascript

Basically I'm trying to await each iteration of the filter loop to only get the object properties of record, newAnalyte, and userId, which all require awaited async methods that take time to process the data.

The other object properties are derived from an iteration of another filter loop that results is in, so I need to wait for each iteration of the outer loop + the inner loop to finish to get a complete data object.

The problem is, what I'm getting back in the completed promise is an array of objects from the full loop instead of one object each from each loop iteration.

What I'm expecting is something like [Object], instead I'm getting [[Object], [Object], [Object], etc].

```
 odbc.connect();
 const results = reqs.filter(async (item , k) => {
   if (k % 2 == 0) {
       const newAnalyte = item['Analyte Peak Name'].split(' ')[0].toUpperCase();

       const validRow = await odbc.findBatch(req, type, batchId, newAnalyte, seq).catch((e) => console.log(e));

       if (validRow.length > 0) {

         let suffix = "";
         if (reqsuffix.length != 0) {
             suffix = reqsuffix[l]['Sample Name'].slice(-4);
         }

         const dbUser = await sqlCreateBatch.checkUser(user).catch((e) => console.log(e));

         const record = await odbc.processAnalyte(item, reqs[k+1], type, req, suffix);

         return ({
             analyte: newAnalyte,
             req: req,
             type: type,
             batchId: batchId,
             seq: seq,
             record: record,
             record1: item,
             record2: reqs[k+1],
             userId: dbUser.row_id,
             rowId: rowId,
             fileId: fileId,
             user: user,
             file: file
         });
       }
     }

 });


  Promise.all(results).then((completed) => {
      console.log("results");

      return completed;
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `filter` will always receive promises, which are truthy values.  Option would be to use `Promise.all` and then filter by index. Of use `for of`.

```
Promise.all(reqs.map(async (item, k) => {
     // make your requests
     // return true or false
})).then((results) => {
     const filteredReqs = reqs.filter((item, index) => results[index]);
});
```

UPDATE:
Misunderstood your code a bit, you need to replace `filter` with `map`. And then filter inside `Promise.all(results).then(....)`